# Insertion of data into a treeview widget on a notebook Tab

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have included two modules:

- A treeview Module
- A notebook Module

The treeview module seems to function as required and gets its data from sample data at the top of the Module

The notebook module creates a notebook with 12 tabs - one for each month of the year. each tab will have a treeview widget on it showing the data for that month.

**Question # 1:**

How do I enter the treeview widget and its data from the treeview module on each tab of the notebook? No Mater what I try I end up with a blank treeview widget as demonstrated in the current module

**Question # 2:**

Column #3 of the treeview module has both negative and positive numbers in it. How do I make the positive numbers "green" and the Negative numbers "red" while keeping the rest of the widget in its default "black".?
(every time I try to use 'tag' and 'tag-configure' it changes all the characters on the widget.)

```
'''the following is a tree module
in order to run this module remove "#" from the last line'''

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

CategoryList = ['Income','Taxes','Housing']
AccountsList = [['Income','Bobs'],['Income','Roses'],['Income','Als'],
                ['Taxes','Federal'],['Taxes','State'],['Taxes','Local'],
                ['Housing','Payment'],['Housing','Utilities'], ['Housing','Repairs']]
CatDiffList = [[5000,4500,500],[100,120,-20],[800,700,100]]
AcctDiffList = [[2000,2000,0],[2000,2000,0],[1000,500,500],
                [70,50,20],[50,50,0],[0,40,-40],
                [500,400,0],[200,100,100],[100,0,100]]

month = 3            #numbers 1 to 12 = the twelve months

def CreateTreeview():
    root = Tk()
    #Set up the tree
    tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height = 20 )
    tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
    tree.column("one", width=100,anchor = 'e' )
    tree.column("two", width=100,anchor = 'e')
    tree.column("three", width=100,anchor = 'e')
    tree.heading('#0',text = "Account Names")
    tree.heading("one", text="Budget")
    tree.heading("two", text="Actual")
    tree.heading("three", text="Difference")

    #Bring in Data from TransactionTotals Module & insert it in the tree
    for r in range(0,len(CategoryList)):
        Name = CategoryList[r]
        CatBud = CatDiffList[r][0]
        CatAct = CatDiffList[r][1]
        CatDif = CatDiffList[r][2]
        if CatDif >= 0:
            fg = "green"          #Change color of column 3
        else:
            fg = "red"
        tree.tag_configure("col3", foreground = fg)
        tree.insert("" , r,Name, text=Name, values=(CatBud,CatAct,CatDif),
                    tag =("col3"))
        AcctBud = AcctDiffList[r][0]
        AcctAct = AcctDiffList[r][1]
        AcctDif = AcctDiffList[r][2]
        if AccttDif >= 0:
            fg = "green"         #Change color of column 3
        else:
            fg = "red"
        tree.tag_configure("col3", foreground = fg)
        for y in range(1,len(AccountsList)):
            if AccountsList[y][0] == Name:
                tree.insert(Name,2,text = AccountsList[y][1],
                            values = (AcctBud,AcctAct,AcctDif),
                            tag =("col3"))
    tree.pack()
    root.mainloop()

#CreateTreeview()   #uncomment this line in order to test Tview.py


*******************************************************************************

'''This is the Notebook Module'''



import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import Tview as T2
from tkinter import *

class Notebook(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, activerelief = RAISED, inactiverelief = RIDGE,    xpad = 4, ypad = 6, activefg = 'black', inactivefg = 'black', **kw):
        """Construct a Notebook Widget

        Notebook(self, parent, activerelief = RAISED, inactiverelief = RIDGE, xpad = 4, ypad = 6, activefg = 'black', inactivefg = 'black', **kw)

        Valid resource names: background, bd, bg, borderwidth, class,
        colormap, container, cursor, height, highlightbackground,
        highlightcolor, highlightthickness, relief, takefocus, visual, width, activerelief,
        inactiverelief, xpad, ypad.

        xpad and ypad are values to be used as ipady and ipadx
        with the Label widgets that make up the tabs. activefg and inactivefg define what
        color the text on the tabs when they are selected, and when they are not"""

       #Make various argument available to the rest of the class
        self.activefg = activefg
        self.inactivefg = inactivefg
        self.deletedTabs = []
        self.xpad = xpad
        self.ypad = ypad
        self.activerelief = activerelief
        self.inactiverelief = inactiverelief
        self.kwargs = kw
        self.tabVars = {}                                                                  #This dictionary holds the label and frame instances of each tab
        self.tabs = 0                                                                      #Keep track of the number of tabs
        self.noteBookFrame = Frame(parent)                                                 #Create a frame to hold everything together
        self.BFrame = Frame(self.noteBookFrame)                                            #Create a frame to put the "tabs" in
        self.noteBook = Frame(self.noteBookFrame, relief = RAISED, bd = 4, **kw)           #Create the frame that will parent the frames for each tab
        self.noteBook.grid_propagate(0)                                                    #self.noteBook has a bad habit of resizing itself, this line prevents that
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.noteBookFrame.grid()
        self.BFrame.grid(row =0, sticky = W)
        self.noteBook.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 27)

    def change_tab(self, IDNum):
        """Internal Function"""
        for i in (a for a in range(0, len(self.tabVars.keys()))):
            if not i in self.deletedTabs:                                                  #Make sure tab hasen't been deleted
                if i != IDNum:                                                             #Check to see if the tab is the one that is currently selected
                    self.tabVars[i][1].grid_remove()                                       #Remove the Frame corresponding to each tab that is not selected
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['relief'] = self.inactiverelief                     #Change the relief of all tabs that are not selected to "Groove"
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['fg'] = self.inactivefg                             #Set the fg of the tab, showing it is selected, default is black
                else:                                                                      #When on the tab that is currently selected...
                    self.tabVars[i][1].grid()                                              #Re-grid the frame that corresponds to the tab
                    self.tabVars[IDNum][0]['relief'] = self.activerelief                   #Change the relief to "Raised" to show the tab is selected
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['fg'] = self.activefg                               #Set the fg of the tab, showing it is not selected, default is black

    def add_tab(self, width = 2, **kw):
        """Creates a new tab, and returns it's corresponding frame"""
        temp = self.tabs                                                                   #Temp is used so that the value of self.tabs will not throw off the argument sent by the label's event binding
        self.tabVars[self.tabs] = [Label(self.BFrame, relief = RIDGE, **kw)]               #Create the tab
        self.tabVars[self.tabs][0].bind("<Button-1>", lambda Event:self.change_tab(temp))  #Makes the tab "clickable"
        self.tabVars[self.tabs][0].pack(side = LEFT, ipady = self.ypad, ipadx = self.xpad) #Packs the tab as far to the left as possible
        self.tabVars[self.tabs].append(Frame(self.noteBook, **self.kwargs))                #Create Frame, and append it to the dictionary of tabs
        self.tabVars[self.tabs][1].grid(row = 0, column = 0)                               #Grid the frame ontop of any other already existing frames
        self.change_tab(0)                                                                 #Set focus to the first tab
        self.tabs += 1                                                                     #Update the tab count
        return self.tabVars[temp][1]                                                       #Return a frame to be used as a parent to other widgets

    def destroy_tab(self, tab):
        """Delete a tab from the notebook, as well as it's corresponding frame"""
        self.iteratedTabs = 0                                                              #Keep track of the number of loops made
        for b in self.tabVars.values():                                                    #Iterate through the dictionary of tabs
            if b[1] == tab:                                                                #Find the NumID of the given tab
                b[0].destroy()                                                             #Destroy the tab's frame, along with all child widgets
                self.tabs -= 1                                                             #Subtract one from the tab count
                self.deletedTabs.append(self.iteratedTabs)                                 #Apend the NumID of the given tab to the list of deleted tabs
                break                                                                      #Job is done, exit the loop
            self.iteratedTabs += 1                                                         #Add one to the loop count

    def focus_on(self, tab):
        """Locate the IDNum of the given tab and use
        change_tab to give it focus"""
        self.iteratedTabs = 0                                                              #Keep track of the number of loops made
        for b in self.tabVars.values():                                                    #Iterate through the dictionary of tabs
            if b[1] == tab:                                                                #Find the NumID of the given tab
                self.change_tab(self.iteratedTabs)                                         #send the tab's NumID to change_tab to set focus, mimicking that of each tab's event bindings
                break                                                                      #Job is done, exit the loop
            self.iteratedTabs += 1                                                         #Add one to the loop count

def NotebookView():


    root = Tk()
    root.title("Yearly Budget Comparison by Month")
    note = Notebook(root, width= 400, height =600, activefg = 'red', inactivefg = 'blue')  #Create a Note book Instance
    note.grid()
    tab1 = note.add_tab(text = " January")
    tab2 = note.add_tab(text = " February")
    tab3 = note.add_tab(text = "March ")                                   #Create a tab with the text "March"
    tab4 = note.add_tab(text = " April")
    tab5 = note.add_tab(text = "May ")
    tab6 = note.add_tab(text = " June")
    tab7 = note.add_tab(text = " July")
    tab8 = note.add_tab(text = "August ")
    tab9 = note.add_tab(text = " September")
    tab10 = note.add_tab(text = " October")
    tab11 = note.add_tab(text = "November ")
    tab12 = note.add_tab(text = " December")

    Label(tab1, text = 'January Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 1,pady = 25,padx = 25)
    Label(tab2, text = 'Febuary Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab3, text = 'March Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab4, text = 'April Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab5, text = 'May Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab6, text = 'June Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab7, text = 'July Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab8, text = 'August Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab9, text = 'September Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab10, text = 'October Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab11, text = 'November Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    Label(tab12, text = 'December Monthly Budget Comparison:',font =("Comic Sans MS", 14, "italic"),fg = 'RED',justify = CENTER).grid(row = 0, column = 7,pady = 25)
    T2.CreateTreeview=ttk.Treeview(tab1,height = 20).grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 6)





    note.focus_on(tab1)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NotebookView()
```

Comment: 1) If you have two questions, ask two questions... 2) Please make a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The notebook module should work on its own. I don't know how to shorten it  except to remove some of the tabs. I will rewrite the TreeView module to include fake data. __ towards the end of the NoteBookView function in the Notebook Module is the line ****** T2.tree=ttk.Treeview(tab1,height = 20).grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 6) It creates a blank treeview widget. The primary Question remains the same. How do you put the components and Data inside the Treeview Widget.?

Comment: Are you aware there is a native notebook widget in the ttk package? There is no need to create your own notebook widget.

Comment: Removing tabs would be a good start. Do you really need 12 tabs to illustrate the problem, or will one or two do?

Answer (score 0):

Without going through all of the code, there is one very clear problem: you are creating two instances of `Tk`, and calling `mainloop` twice. Within a single GUI you should only ever create exactly once instance, and call `mainloop` exactly once.